# How to convert exec to spawn?

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process, npm-scripts

I was using `exec` with the following code to execute a script with NPM, and it was working very well.

```
const { exec, spawn } = require('promisify-child-process')

await exec(`npm run start ${key}  ${scriptVariables[key]}`)
```

Then i started to get this error:

> RangeError [ERR_CHILD_PROCESS_STDIO_MAXBUFFER]: stdout maxBuffer length exceeded

So I assume the buffer is an issue, and have changed it to:

```
await exec(`npm run start ${key}-Product  ${UrlsArray[i]}`, {maxBuffer: 4096 * 4096})
```

which was better, but still get some errors once in a while.
So from what I read, I need to change to `spawn`, and striking not buffering.

But this one doesn't work:

```
await spawn(`npm run start ${key}-Product ${UrlsArray[i]}`)
```

Any idea how to convert to code?

Comment: By the way, your `exec()` code is problematic... potentially a massive security risk.  Never concatenate parameters directly into a command like that.  They need to be escaped first, at a minimum.  You won't have this issue with `spawn`, since the arguments are sent separately.

Answer (score 1):

For `spawn`, you need to provide the arguments as an array:

```js
await spawn(
  'npm',
  ['run', 'start', `${key}-Product`, UrlsArray[i]],
  {maxBuffer: 4096 * 4096}
);
```

However this won't solve your errors if it's related to maxBuffer length,
you still need to augment the limit.
If your use-case allows it, you can also use streaming instead of reading
the whole output up front. You can also try removing some output from that
npm script.

Here is an example using streaming, from the Node.js docs:

```js
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
const ls = spawn('ls', ['-lh', '/usr']);

ls.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
});

ls.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
  console.error(`stderr: ${data}`);
});

ls.on('close', (code) => {
  console.log(`child process exited with code ${code}`);
});
```